# How to patch com_google_protobuf/python/google/__init__.py?

Tags: python, bazel

My Python project depends implicitly on protobuf. Once build, under `master.runfiles` there is the directory `com_google_protobuf`. The problem is that `master.runfiles/com_google_protobuf/python/google/__init__.py` is empty, blocking possibility to import `google.rpc` from another package. It could be fixed by replacing content of `master.runfiles/com_google_protobuf/python/google/__init__.py` by

```
try:
  __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
  __path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

but I have no idea how to achieve that?

Ideally I'd love to know what dependency installed this old version of `com_google_protobuf`?

Comment: *"Ideally I'd love to know what dependency installed this old version of com_google_protobuf"* It's impossible to answer since we don't know what version you are talking about nor any of your dependencies...

Comment: Also, an empty `__init__.py` should not block importing modules or submodules, it might just make it a bit harder. What exactly does your code try to import?

Comment: What does the part of your `WORKSPACE` where you import this look like? Most external repository rules support patches in some form, but the details depend on which one you're using.

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm trying to `from google.rpc.error_details_pb2 import RetryInfo`. Because first `google` dir on sys.path is `com_google_protobuf/python/google` which doesn't contain `rpc` and has empty `__init__.py` then namespace module search is disabled and import returns an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'rpc' from 'google'`